# PHP array element starting with "<" weird behavior

Tags: php, arrays

I was trying to create some syntax for my application that uses $operator.$columnField as elements of an array for SELECT WHERE clause - something like selecting all ids less than 41 would have been

```
$parameters['where'] = array('<id'),
$parameters['fields'] = array(':id' => '41')
```

Then I would have parsed all ['where']s in order to determine the operator from the field itself. The main idea here is not if my way is a good way, given the fact that I can do it in a lot of different approaches. I am interested in the fact that it seems '<' plays some specific role if at the beginning of an array element of type string.

I noticed that there were some errors, so I started testing. Now can anyone tell me why

```
print_r(array('alfa', '<beta', 'gamma'));
```

echoes

```
Array ( 
      [0] => alfa 
      [1] => gamma 
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Later Edit: If the '<' character is followed by a space, the same does not apply any longer. It simply outputs

```
Array ( 
      [0] => alfa 
      [1] => < beta 
      [2] => gamma 
)
```

Comment: i don't think so. see your output of print_r(array('alfa', '<beta', 'gamma')); Demo  :  https://eval.in/87530

Comment: for your last edit check that: https://eval.in/87535  You actually have correct string in your array. when you are viewing it in browser it seems that you do not see the difference. you should see the output by viewing source of the html page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually works.. The **`<`** tag is intrepreted by the browser and it is hiding it from you.

Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to view the source. You will see this..

```
Array
(
    [0] => alfa
    [1] => <beta
    [2] => gamma
)
```

Well , if you want it for display purposes.. Do like this..

```
<?php
print_r(array_map('htmlentities',array('alfa', '<beta', 'gamma')));
```

Comment: Oh. Right. How stupid of me. Sorry for such an idiotic question. I simply forgot about that. Thank you.